# Why is a "Brute Force Protection" dialog appearing on login? How to remove?

Tags: login, security

After successfully logging into admin I seem to be getting this message in a browser auth dialog:

**Brute force protection, Please use these credentials: User = 'u' and Password is the answer to 1+1”**

What's causing this and how do I disable it? Very annoying!

Thanks

Comment: Sounds sketchy. I just searched the Craft app folder for "Brute force protection" and "Please use these credentials" and don't get any matching results.

Comment: Are you on shared hosting? I wonder if this is something that a hosting provider setup for http auth on urls like /admin ? Can you take a screenshot?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - it may be related to this precaution our shared host have taken:

https://support.webhost.co.nz/index.php?/Openhost/Knowledgebase/Article/View/790/154/wordpress-brute-force-attack-prevention-system

Seems Craft has been lumped in with the Wordpress solution :(

Comment: All signs point to this being an issue with hosting, not with Craft. Closing this as "off topic".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a hosting issue, not a Craft issue.

Answer (score 1):

That message definitely isn't coming from Craft natively.

My guess is either:

1. You've got a Craft plugin installed that's listening to [onBeforeLogin](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#userSession-onBeforeLogin) and/or [onLogin](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#userSession-onLogin) events and is performing some custom business logic
2. Your host has some library/extension/etc. installed globally that is affecting your Craft install.

Comment: Thanks Brad- I was actually going to delete it outright, turns out it is the host.